# Counting end value of multiple arrays - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a hard time finding out how to count the ending value of multiple arrays. Let me give you an example:

Here I have four arrays:

```
let numberOne: [string] = ["...", "...", "car"]
let numberTwo: [string] = ["...", "...", "bike"]
let numberThree: [string] = ["...", "...", "car"]
let numberFour: [string] = ["...", "...", "car"]
```

Lets say those are my arrays. I do not know, however, how many arrays there are each time, can be between 1 and 14.

How do I show a count for how many arrays there is containing an ending value of, for instance, `car`?

Hope you can help me :-)

Comment: So you are always declaring 14 variables for 14 arrays in your code and at runtime your app uses between 1 and all of them? Did I understand correctly? Just to be sure.

Comment: Yes exactly @EricAya.. I mean based on how many of the variables that are being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
func countLastEelement(){
    let numberOne: [String] = ["...", "...", "car"]
    let numberTwo: [String] = ["...", "...", "bike"]
    let numberThree: [String] = ["...", "...", "car"]
    let numberFour: [String] = ["...", "...", "car"]

    let numbers:[[String]] = [numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour]

    var count:Int! = 0

    for number in numbers {
        if number[number.count-1] == "car" {
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
    print(count) // output: 3
}
```

Another:

```
for number in numbers {
    if number.last == "car"{
        count = count + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! Exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: There is a problem though. Sometimes there will be four arrays like the above example, but I do not know how many arrays there will be everytime. And if I for instance remove the numberFour, then I of course get and error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: show more code for help.how do you create arrays, where the data comes from?

Comment: The user creates the data. Whatever the users wants to do, adds between 1 and 14 arrays.

Comment: Are you declaring 14 arrays?

Comment: I have 14 variables. Some of them are being used (have arrays in them) some don't, since the user did not need more

Comment: show the code where you are assigning data to the arrays.

Comment: @Mr.UB Note that you don't need to use an implicilty unwrapped optional here: `var count:Int! = 0`. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more pseudo-code than an exact example, there may be syntax problems.  But this will give you a dictionary, count and the select arrays for any given last element.  It may be overkill, but you didn't exactly say what you wanted out of this, so I decided to get as much data as possible.

```
var arraySet : [Array] = [[]] //Your set of arrays
var unique : [String:[Array]] = [:]
for array in arraySet{
    if(unique[array.last] == nil)
    {
        unique[array.last] = [array]
    }
    else
    {
        unique[array.last] += [array]
    }
}
```